# How do I create this stored procedure in snowflake?

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have this SQL Statements:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TEST_PROCEDURE_STOCKEE_TABLE_KPI AS 

SELECT *
FROM TABLE A
```

I would like to transform this SQL statement in stored procedure and for the moment i try this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_stored_procedure()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
BEGIN

SELECT *
FROM TABLE A
RETURN 'Success';
END;
$$;
```

But I have this error message:

```
SQL compilation error: parse error line 1 at position 3 near '<EOF>'. syntax error line 1 at position 1 unexpected '$'
```

I would like to store this SQL statement to put this in a task then and call this task every day to create/update this table every day.

Comment: Why do you need the Stored Procedure? Can you just put that query in your Task?

Comment: i'm beginner in sql, i suppose it's more easy to put this query in a stored procedure then use it in a task

Comment: I'm having difficulty reproducing this error. Please share actual SQL that replicates this error (for example "Table A" and "Table B" wouldn't parse correctly, so I think you've changed the SQL from what actually gives you the error you're reporting). Also: how are you executing this? From Snowflake's web UI? Is this the first statement in your worksheet, or is there something above it?

Comment: i've edit my question adding my real request ;)

Comment: i use VSCode with extension Snowflake Driver for SQLTools

Comment: ok, i've my response, it's because i use the extension vscode but if i run this sql statements in the snowflake console it's ok :)

Answer (score 1):

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_stored_procedure()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
BEGIN
  CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE example 
  AS 
  SELECT col1, MAX(col2) AS col2, MAX(col3) AS col3 -- agg function
  FROM Table A
  LEFT JOIN Table B 
    ON A.col1 = B.col2
  WHERE col3 = 'XXXX'
  GROUP BY 1;

  RETURN 'Success';
END;
$$;
```

Comment: why didn't you put brackets to create table ?

Comment: @MaxMamazita They are not necessary when using CTAS

Comment: CTAS ? (I've edit my question adding my real request)

Comment: @MaxMamazita Create Table As Select

Comment: ok thanks for tips, but, despite this, i've always the same error message

Comment: @MaxMamazita The question was updated third time in place. Anyway: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/running-examples.html, you could try changing delimeter to `'` and/or wrapping with`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`